# Compose Email issues in Swift version 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, email

For some reason, I can't seem to get my compose email to work under swift 2.0.  I did worked fine under swift version 1, but no longer work on version 2.  Any suggestion?  Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

    class EmailViewController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate  {

       let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

        @IBAction func SendEmailButton(sender: AnyObject) {

            let fields: [UITextField] = [name, phone, email]

            let messageBody = "Name:\(name.text)\nPhone:\(phone.text)\nEmail:\(email.text)"

            let emailTitle = "Interface Information"
            let toRecipents = [""]
            let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
            mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
            mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
            self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

            name.text = userDefaults.stringForKey("name")  
            phone.text = userDefaults.stringForKey("phone")
            email.text = userDefaults.stringForKey("email")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works fine for me, do you get any error messages? I would guess you have have some issues with your text fields.

Comment: Yeah.  The textfield data doesn't transfer to email body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some issues with your textfields. I would probably guess that the outlets does not work and you could test to drag them again. I created a sample project for you that you can check how I have done it with your code and see if it helps you. You can download the code from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oioxm81xw6s6m6o/MailTest.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into it.